# Async/await in Express with multiple MongoDB queries

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, asynchronous, async-await

I have a fairly straightforward CRUD app which renders the results of two queries onto one page. The problem that arose once I got this to "work" was that the page required a refresh in order to display the results. On first load, no results were displayed.

I came to figure out that this is a problem/symptom of Node's asynchronous nature. I've been trying to approach this problem by using async/await, and from hours of messing with things, I feel like I'm quite close to the solution, but it's just not working out - I still need a manual refresh to display/render the results on the .ejs page.

The code:

```
var entries = [];
var frontPageGoals = [];

app.get('/entries', async (req,res) => {
  if (req.session.password) {

      const entriesColl = await 
            db.collection('entries')
            .find()
            .sort({date: -1})
            .toArray((err, result) => {
               if (err) { console.log(err) }
               else {
                  for (i=0; i<result.length; i++) {
                       entries[i] = result[i];
                  }
               }
            });

      const goalsColl = await 
            db.collection('goals')
            .find()
            .toArray((err, result) => {
               if (err) {console.log(err)}
               else {
                  for (i=0; i<result.length; i++) {
                       frontPageGoals[i] = result[i];
                  }
               }
            });

      res.render('index.ejs', {entries: entries, frontPageGoals: frontPageGoals});
   }
   else {
      res.redirect('/');
   }
 });
```

Now, I can conceive of a few problems here, but honestly I'm just at my wits end trying to figure this out. For example, I'm sure it's problematic that the empty lists which will contain the results to be passed when the page renders are outside the actual async function. But after trying to move them a dozen different places within the async area... still no dice.

Any help would be hugely appreciated! This is basically the last big "thing" I need done for this app.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure about your database driver, but assuming that the `toArray()` returns a promise (which it does in the default mongodb driver), the `await` will actually return the value you expect in your callback, `result` in your case, or in case there was an error, which you expected it as `err` in your callback, it will be thrown, thus forcing you to use `try-catch` blocks, in your case, you would just use `console.log(err)` in the catch block, since you aren't doing any handling

Here's your code after updating :

```
app.get("/entries", async (req, res) => {
  if (req.session.password) {
    try {
      const entries = await db
        .collection("entries")
        .find()
        .sort({ date: -1 })
        .toArray();

      const frontPageGoals = await db
        .collection("goals")
        .find()
        .toArray();

      res.render("index.ejs", {
        entries: entries,
        frontPageGoals: frontPageGoals
      });
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  } else {
    res.redirect("/");
  }
});
```

**EDIT**

However, if you don't know about promises -which `async/await` are basically promises-, and wanna just do it using callbacks -*not advised*-, you would have to just send your response in the callback, and nest the 2nd query in the first query's callback, here is the code,, with some comments to hopefully help you out:

```
app.get("/entries", (req, res) => {
  if (req.session.password) {
    // First query
    db.collection("entries")
      .find()
      .sort({ date: -1 })
      .toArray((err, entryResult) => {
        if (err) {
          console.log(err);
        } else {
          // In the callback of the first query, so it will
          // execute 2nd query, only when the first one is done
          db.collection("goals")
            .find()
            .toArray((err, frontPageResult) => {
              if (err) {
                console.log(err);
              } else {
                // In the callback of the 2nd query, send the response
                // here since both data are at hand
                res.render("index.ejs", {
                  entries: entryResult,
                  frontPageGoals: frontPageResult
                });
              }
            });
        }
      });
  } else {
    res.redirect("/");
  }
});
```

- I have removed the `async` keyword since you no longer need it
- I renamed the callback arguments, instead of just `result`, because both callbacks would have the same argument name, and you would have had to store it in a temp variable

Comment: That did it! Thank you so much! So, to sort of post-mortem this... If I'm understanding correctly, I was almost doubling-up on the promises? I didn't realize toArray() returned a promise.

Comment: Kinda yes, using callbacks with `async/await` usually defeats the purpose, since providing a callback to a function (in your case, using mongo driver functions), usually makes the function not return a promise.

Comment: Makes sense! I stumbled upon this in the MongoDB documentation a short while ago; that if no callback is specified within .toArray(), then it simply returns a promise. Good to know!